# Getting "Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches for web application" error while starting app- tomcat8

Tags: java, spring, maven, war, tomcat8

I am getting " java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.Map" error while starting app on tomcat8. Below are some of the important files from my reporsitory.

Below is the complete stack trace

```
02-Mar-2024 21:02:30.255 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches Failed to clear soft references from ObjectStreamClass$Caches for web application [crudapp]
        java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches$1 and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearCache(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2331)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2306)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1675)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1605)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:455)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5505)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:175)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1405)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:697)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:661)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:378)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:56)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1673)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.crudexample</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoexample</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/crudapp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent\main\webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="admin" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.example.crudexample.demoexample.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    
    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.example.crudexample.demoexample.PersonDAO">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.example.crudexample.demoexample.PersonService">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.crudexample.demoexample" />
    
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Below is project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq9bh.png)

Comment: If you are using spring boot parent you should NOT overwrite versions of components like hibernate etc. hibernate is at version 6+ in SB 3.2.3 etc. The spring framework version shouldn't be overwritten use the one which is provided by SB itself... also remove references to log4j 1.2+ which is vulnerable... and also remove the ancient old version of plugins eclipse plugin which end of life since 2015, why using ancient old tomcat version etc... there are so many things wronge

Comment: @khmarbaise i am not using springboot framework but spring verison 6.1.4. Also, i am not using eclipse but visual studio and i deployed the war file using maven .\mvnw tomcat7:deploy command. 

i had to downgrade the tomcat version to 8 as i was getting some which was solved as per suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73452314/java-lang-illegalstateexception-error-starting-child.

Please suggest now.

Comment: @khmarbaise i think the issue was with <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> in web.xml removing this solved the issue.

Comment: You are using the spring boot parent???